# "Name" for bitstream in Dspace when added through API is null?

Tags: api, postman, dspace

I am trying to add a bitstream to an Item through Postman.When I post , I chose body as "form-data" and added a key as "file" and selected a file.In addition to it I have given key as "name" and value as the file name. It is getting successfully added to the Item but the name is null.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us, what version of DSpace you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use DSpace 6.

---

First: Make sure you are logged in. Get the JSESSIONID cookie by calling

```
Post: http://yourserver.com/rest/login
```

with `Query Params` `email` and `password`

---

Then: Post the Bitstream like this

```
Post: http://yourserver.com/rest/items/your-item-id/bitstreams
```

Add the file under `Body` and select `binary`:

[image: Add file. DSpace 6 API / Postman]

Set `filename` and `description` as `Query Params`:

[image: Add filename and description for bitstream. DSpace 6 API / Postman]

Hit send.